# kotlin coroutines disk violation strict mode

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, android-strictmode

I have lifecycle aware coroutine

```
abstract class AppViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

if i use in my viewmodel

```
launch {

}
```

it causes disk violation

> D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=200 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation

on this line

```
get() = Dispatchers.Main + job
```

what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT

I have created another example, and this error still exists

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {

    protected val job = SupervisorJob()
    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        launch {
            val e = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                4
            }

            text.text = e.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your code in `launch` block?

Comment: it is empty block, just to show that inner code does not affect to this error

Comment: suppose it somehow depends on this issue: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/878

Comment: I am also having the same problem. even I am using dispatcher IO. If you solove the problem please post solution.  fun specialWork() = liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO +  handler) { }

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to execute queries in the UI thread. According to your code try to change coroutine context in that way:

```
//Code here stays same
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
  get() = Dispatchers.IO + job
//Code here stays same
```

So here you will launch your coroutines on the IO-threads and off the UI-thread.

Hopefully it'll help!

Comment: `viewModelScope` is best used with the Dispatcher